# Prove that the rings $\Bbb Z[X]$ and $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$ are not isomorphic

Tags: ring-theory

> Prove that the rings $\Bbb Z[X]$ and $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$ are not isomorphic.

Can someone give me some hints on where to start ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about ideals?

Answer (score 10):

There are many proofs. For example:

First proof:  If $\mathbb{Z}[X] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$, then (by modding out the ideal $(2)$) we also get $\mathbb{F}_2[X] \cong \mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]$. But $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ is a principal ideal domain, and $\mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]$ is not.

Second proof: If $\mathbb{Z}[X] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$, then for every commutative ring $A$ with underlying set $|A|$ we have $|A| \cong \hom(\mathbb{Z}[X],A) \cong \hom(\mathbb{Z}[X,Y],A) \cong |A|^2$. If $|A|$ is finite, this would imply $|A| = 0$ or $|A|=1$, which is absurd (take $A=\mathbb{F}_2$).

Third proof: The Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is $2$, whereas the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ is $3$. But this requires some dimension theory.

In any case, you should remember the following basic technique which is used in all the proofs above (also in the answer by user129924): In order to show that two structures are not isomorphic, one tries to find an *invariant* which has the property that isomorphic structures have the same invariant. Then it is enough to show that the invariants differ.

Comment: +1 I like the second proof most because it just uses the universal property and voila.

Comment: @Hagen: I also like it most. Actually the general case ($R[S] \cong R[T] \Rightarrow S \cong T$ for sets $S,T$) can be reduced to the case of finite $R,S,T$ by common techniques, and then one just counts.

Answer (score 4):

Their field of quotients are $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(X,Y)$ resp. so their transcendence degrees over $\mathbb{Q}$ are $1$ and $2$ respectively. Hence they can not be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a low-tech solution, it only uses the concept of degree.

Suppose $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is an isomorphism. Notice that the map is determined entirely by $\varphi(x)$. In fact, for a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have $\varphi(f(x)) = f(\varphi(x))$ (you should show this if you haven't seen it before).

Now set $\varphi(x) = g(x,y)$, so the image of $\varphi$ is precisely the polynomials of the form $f(g(x,y))$. We need $x$ to be in the image. What does this mean about $g(x,y)$? Think about the degree of $y$ in $g(x,y)$ and in $f(g(x,y))$. Now with this conclusion and very similar reasoning, you should be able to show that $y$ can not be in the image.